# How to add a description at discord.py to the parameters of slash commands in cogs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to add a description at discord.py to the parameters of slash commands in cogs? Without Cogs I could just use @app_commands.describe() but that doesn't work anymore
Here is the code:

**main.py**

```
import bot
import asyncio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(bot.run()) # Run main method

    except Exception as error:
        print("Script Ending") # Error handling
        raise(error)
```

**bot.py**

```
bot = Client()
async def run():
    async with bot:
        await bot.start(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

**client.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=";", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        await self.load_extension("Commands.Slash.bumpreminder_sc")
        await self.tree.sync()
```

**bumpreminder_sc.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from Handlers.bumpreminder_handler import Bumpreminder_Handler
from Classes.bumpreminder import Bumpreminder
from typing import Union
from typing import Optional

class Bumpreminder_SC(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @discord.app_commands.command(name="setbumpreminder", description="Setzt einen Bumpreminder")
    async def CreateBumpreminder_SC(interaction: discord.Interaction, test: str, message: str, textchannel: discord.TextChannel):
        bumpreminder = Bumpreminder(); bumpreminder.InputData([None, 2, test, message, textchannel.id, interaction.guild_id])
        await Bumpreminder_Handler.CreateBumpreminder(interaction, bumpreminder)

async def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    await client.add_cog(Bumpreminder_SC(client))
```

I searched Google, the discord.py docs and Stack Overflow for a solution to my problem and also tried to solve it myself:
**bumpreminder_sc.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from Handlers.bumpreminder_handler import Bumpreminder_Handler
from Classes.bumpreminder import Bumpreminder
from typing import Union
from typing import Optional

class Bumpreminder_SC(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @discord.app_commands.command(name="setbumpreminder", description="Setzt einen Bumpreminder")
    @discord.app_commands.describe(test = "Test")
    async def CreateBumpreminder_SC(interaction: discord.Interaction, test: str, message: str, textchannel: discord.TextChannel):
        bumpreminder = Bumpreminder(); bumpreminder.InputData([None, 2, test, message, textchannel.id, interaction.guild_id])
        await Bumpreminder_Handler.CreateBumpreminder(interaction, bumpreminder)

async def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    await client.add_cog(Bumpreminder_SC(client))
```

**Error:**

> Exception has occurred: ExtensionFailed
> Extension 'Commands.Slash.bumpreminder_sc' raised an error: TypeError: unknown parameter given: test
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\Commands\Slash\bumpreminder_sc.py", line 9, in 
> class Bumpreminder_SC(commands.Cog):
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\Commands\Slash\bumpreminder_sc.py", line 13, in Bumpreminder_SC
> @discord.app_commands.command(name="setbumpreminder", description="Setzt einen Bumpreminder")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: unknown parameter given: test
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\client.py", line 9, in setup_hook
> await self.load_extension("Commands.Slash.bumpreminder_sc")
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\bot.py", line 202, in run
> await bot.start(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\main.py", line 10, in 
> raise(error)
> File "C:\Users\mabbe\Progammieren\Entwicklung\Discordbots_PD\OnlinePlaza-Bot\main.py", line 10, in 
> raise(error)
> discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'Commands.Slash.bumpreminder_sc' raised an error: TypeError: unknown parameter given: test

Comment: Did you also try to describe the parameter in the docstring?

Comment: @Dominik do you mean that? @discord.app_commands.command(message="test", name="setbumpreminder", description="Setzt einen Bumpreminder") No, unfortunately that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've found a working solution. The problem is that Cogs requires an additional parameter. I don't know exactly what it's good for, but most of the time it's called "self". Here is the code:

```
@app_commands.command(description='Bans a member')
    @app_commands.describe(member='the member to ban')
    async def ban(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Banned {member}')
```